# Splitting CamelCase with regex

Tags: c#, regex, camelcasing

I have this code to split CamelCase by regular expression:

```
Regex.Replace(input, "(?<=[a-z])([A-Z])", " $1", RegexOptions.Compiled).Trim();
```

However, it doesn't split this correctly: `ShowXYZColours`

It produces `Show XYZColours` instead of `Show XYZ Colours`

How do I get the desired result?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unicode-aware

```
(?=\p{Lu}\p{Ll})|(?<=\p{Ll})(?=\p{Lu})
```

Breakdown:

```
(?=               # look-ahead: a position followed by...
  \p{Lu}\p{Ll}    #   an uppercase and a lowercase
)                 #
|                 # or
(?<=              # look-behind: a position after...
  \p{Ll}          #   an uppercase
)                 #
(?=               # look-ahead: a position followed by...
  \p{Lu}          #   a lowercase
)                 #
```

Use with your regex split function.

---

EDIT: Of course you can replace `\p{Lu}` with `[A-Z]` and `\p{Ll}` with `[a-z]` if that's what you need or your regex engine does not understand Unicode categories.

Answer (score 12):

**[.NET DEMO](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=e5eaf039-fb23-420b-9e8d-645e9557adde)**

You can use something like this :

```
(?<=[a-z])([A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])([A-Z][a-z])
```

**CODE :**

```
string strRegex = @"(?<=[a-z])([A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])([A-Z][a-z])";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None);
string strTargetString = @"ShowXYZColours";
string strReplace = @" $1$2";

return myRegex.Replace(strTargetString, strReplace);
```

OUTPUT :

```
Show XYZ Colours
```

**[Demo and Explanation](http://regex101.com/r/nM6sJ2)**

Comment: That's losing the "Co" in "Colours"

Answer (score 3):

using Tomalak's regex with .NET System.Text.RegularExpressions creates an empty entry in position 0 of the resulting array:

```
Regex.Split("ShowXYZColors", @"(?=\p{Lu}\p{Ll})|(?<=\p{Ll})(?=\p{Lu})")

{string[4]}
    [0]: ""
    [1]: "Show"
    [2]: "XYZ"
    [3]: "Colors"
```

It works for caMelCase though (as opposed to PascalCase):

```
Regex.Split("showXYZColors", @"(?=\p{Lu}\p{Ll})|(?<=\p{Ll})(?=\p{Lu})")

{string[3]}
    [0]: "show"
    [1]: "XYZ"
    [2]: "Colors"
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this :**

```
Regex.Replace(input, "((?<!^)([A-Z][a-z]|(?<=[a-z])[A-Z]))", " $1").Trim();
```

**Example :**

```
Regex.Replace("TheCapitalOfTheUAEIsAbuDhabi", "((?<!^)([A-Z][a-z]|(?<=[a-z])[A-Z]))", " $1").Trim();
```

**Output :**
The Capital Of The UAE Is Abu Dhabi