# generate search words from text with CamelCase by using regEx

Tags: regex, autohotkey

I want from this text with CamelCase search words to generate.
I do not know if that's possible only with RegEx. but I'm already close.
I use it in the scripting language AutoHotkey (https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/RegEx-QuickRef.htm) .

data: **reCommended for future AutoHotkeyReleases.**

regEx: `(((\b[^A-Z\s]*)?([A-Z][a-z]+)|([\W_-]?[a-z]+)))` ( https://regex101.com/r/NgRmXZ/2 )

expected Groups:

```
reCommended 
re
Commended 
for
future
Auto
Hotkey
AutoHotkey
HotkeyReleases
Releases
AutoHotkeyReleases.
```

i also tried, but not works for me:

`(?=\p{Lu}\p{Ll})|(?<=\p{Ll})(?=\p{Lu})` from [Splitting CamelCase with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21326963/splitting-camelcase-with-regex)

`(([a-z]*)(?<=[a-z])((?:[A-Z])[a-z]+))` https://regex101.com/r/NgRmXZ/3

`(?<=[a-z])([A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])([A-Z][a-z])` https://regex101.com/r/NgRmXZ/4

`((?<!^)([A-Z][a-z]+|(?<=[a-z])[A-Z][a-z]+))` https://regex101.com/r/B5vXaZ/1

I have started to implement my prototyp already  here:
https://gist.github.com/sl5net/ba5aef19f44fe68204ccb6c96e7c96e0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a regex that almost satisfies your need. However, I'm missing one combination. I don't think, it's possible, because it would require parantheses to overlap, the `'Hotkey'` would have to be part of two different overlapping Groups.

Well, here's the regex:

```
/\b((\w+?(?=[A-Z]|\b))([A-Z][a-z]*)?)([A-Z][a-z]*)?/g
```

It starts by a Word `boundary`, then creates 2 Groups, `Group 2` matches any `Word` character one or more times (ungreedy) until a `look ahead` for a `Capital` letter OR a Word `boundary` is reached.

Group 3 will match a `Capital` letter followed by zero or more `lowercase` letters. That is optional.

`Group 1` combines `Group 2` and `Group 3`.

Finally `Group 4` will match a `Capital` letter followed by zero or more `lowercase` letters. That is optional.

As mentioned, I don't think its possible to create a Group, that combines Group 3 and Group 4, since they overlap. Other than that, this should Work, as you want.

Comment: it works also in autohotkey specific regEx. i implemeted it here:  https://github.com/sl5net/global-IntelliSense-everywhere-Nightly-Build/blob/master/Source/tests/test_getAutoKeywords.ahk